PowerShell script fails when run through Windows Task Scheduler on one machine
We have one machine where running a task in task scheduler doesn't work.
It's running a PowerShell script that checks for write protections on a excel file and the runs a macro. If I run the script direct (from the same machine) it works fine. If I run the PowerShell script through a .bat file, it also works fine.
The PowerShell script is as follows:
## Create path variable

$path =  'C:\XX\XX\XX.xlsm'
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Excel.visible = $false


$file = Get-Item $path

if ($file.IsReadOnly -eq $true)  
{  
  $file.IsReadOnly = $false   
}  


## Open workbook

$Workbook = $excel.Workbooks.open($path)



# Access the Application object and run a macro 

$app = $excel.Application 
$app.Run("Update")
$excel.Quit()     



if ($file.IsReadOnly -eq $false)  
{  
  $file.IsReadOnly = $true   
}

If I run it through task scheduler with my own user and "run only when user is logged on", it works.
If I run it through task scheduler with my own user but "run whether user is log..." it doesn't work.
However we have a service user for this specific purpose and if I use this, it doesn't work at all.
The kicker here is that the same service user is running tons of similar jobs, from the same machine working within the same directories and its never been a problem before.
We checked permissions to the directories involved, and even tried moving the target file to be processed locally on the machine but it still wont run through task scheduler.
Also the history doesn't provide any information at all, simply stating for each run that it was successful.
Anyone have any suggestions on what do check for?

"If I run it through task scheduler with my own user but "run whether user is log..." it doesn't work." Are you only testing it ad hoc/manually? You cannot run tasks interactively with Windows Task Scheduler when the option "Run whether the user is logged in or not" is selected.

@TylerH I have tried both, none of them worked.  I get the same results no matter if I run it ad hoc or scheduled. And the worst part is the log of task scheduler says its completed successfully.
